# How do I imbed Vue/Vuetify components within other Vue/Vuetify components within Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I set myself a goal early this year of learning Laravel, Vue and Vuetify, none of which I have previously used. This has proven quite difficult since most tutorials and videos for Laravel don't touch on Vue, most material for Vue don't touch on how to use Vue in Laravel, and none of the material I've found so far discusses how to use Vuetify in a Laravel environment using Vue components. That means it's very hard to find answers to some of my questions. I've got Vue working within Laravel now and also have Vuetify working at a basic level but I'm still struggling with certain basics.

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out how to make a Vue component that uses Vuetify in Laravel to imbed *another* Vue component in Laravel. I've got a basic To Do List CRUD written that works reasonably well when all in one Vue component. I'm wondering if it's possible to have, for example, my Logo (in a v-toolbar) and a footer each in separate Vue components (that use Vuetify) and then imbed them back in the main component?

If it *is* possible, what would it look like? I've tried putting my Logo (which is a v-toolbar) in its own component but I'm having trouble getting it registered correctly.

Here's my component, called Logo.vue:

```
<template>
    <v-toolbar dark src="images/fence.jpg" max-height="60">
    <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Different Logo</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>
</template>

<script>
export default { 
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Here's my main component, called VuetifyComponent.vue, with most of the body stripped out since it's irrelevant:

```
<template>
  <v-app>

    <v-toolbar
      dark
      src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/vbanner.jpg"
      max-height="60"
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>LaraVuetify To Do List</v-toolbar-title>

    </v-toolbar>

    <Logo></Logo>

  </v-app>
</template>
```

Here's my app.js with its attempt at registering both components:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Form from './Form'
window.Form = Form

import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
Vue.use(Vuetify);
    
Vue.component('vuetify-component', require('./components/VuetifyComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('Logo', require('./components/Logo.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify()
});
```

And here's the message from my browser:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <Logo> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <VuetifyComponent> at resources/js/components/VuetifyComponent.vue
       <Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I did one little thing wrong. The logo component should have been registered with a lowercase "logo" instead of "Logo", in other words this:

```
Vue.component('logo', require('./components/Logo.vue').default);
```

and the tags in my VuetifyComponent should have said `<logo></logo>`.

With those tiny changes made, I've proved that I can imbed one component within another even if both Vue components use Vuetify and both components are in Laravel.